# Can I write I worked as a referee in a journal in my CV?

Tags: phd, research-process, career-path, professorship, cv

I have recently reviewed an article. I am applying for a Ph.D. position nowadays so I am upgrading my CV and writing the professors. Is it ok if I write that I worked as a referee and mention the journal name in the CV? (As I have a part named 'Scientific and Community services' in my CV.)
Also, this is the same journal where all my articles have been published until now

Comment: You've asked this question a few times. What answer do you expect that you haven't gotten so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but it won't mean a tremendous amount in any evaluation. But probably better to list it than not. And the section you suggest is the correct place for it.

It is immaterial whether you have published there or not, assuming, only, that the journal is reputable.

Comment: @Buffy- If that's the case, I think this will be more suitable to include in my motivational letter?

Comment: Actually, I think the CV is the better place. Don't waste space elsewhere that could be used for more important things.